# JavaFX: Styling application with CSS Selectors

Tags: css, javafx, javafx-8

I have a couple of questions about **styling a JavaFX application with CSS Selectors** (such as: `.table-view` for every `TableView`).

I have created a main CSS-file, in which I want to define the universal style properties for my application. For example: every `TableView` gets the same color in every screen. I just import the `Main.css` in every .css that is associated with a .fxml file.

Now I would like to style every `HBox` in a 'sidebar' the same way. I have tried it like this (as suggested in Oracle's documentation):

```
.sidebar > .hbox {
    /* Just some styling */
}
```

This is not working to my surprise, but the following pieces of code are working:

```
.sidebar > HBox {
    /* Just some styling */
}

.sidebar HBox {
    /* Just some styling */
}
```

Maybe it has something to do with the fact that `.sidebar` is a custom style, but I am not sure about this.

So my questions are:

**1. Why isn't the first one working?**

**2. What should be the way to do this? (with `.hbox` or `HBox` and `>` or nothing?)**

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As you can see in the CSS documentation the `HBOX` class has no style class defined. Therefore you can't simply use `.hbox`
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#hbox

If you want to lookup only direct children of the toolbar the `>` sign can be used. Using the `>` sign in a CSS selector will have some benefit in performance issues because by doing so not the complete child hierarchy under the Toolbar Control need to be scanned. Matching Nodes will only be searched in the first hierarchy of children.

So if you want to select all buttons that are direct children of a sidebar you can do the following:

```
. sidebar > .button
```

But if you really want to style all button in a sidebar (even if they are wrapped in panes, etc.) you need to use the following selector:

```
.sidebar .button
```

Back to your HBOX question: Even if the HBOX has no defined style class (.hbox) it has a type that can be used for a type selector. As described in the CSS doc all nodes have a type:

> Node's getTypeSelector method returns a String which is analogous to a
>   CSS Type Selector. By default, this method returns the simple name of
>   the class. Note that the simple name of an inner class or of an
>   anonymous class may not be usable as a type selector. In such a case,
>   this method should be overridden to return a meaningful value.

Because of that the HBOX selector is working.

Comment: That was exactly the answer I was looking for! First time I have seen this information (especially about direct children and using `>`). Weird that I have seen people using `.hbox` in some books, while it is not working. Thank you very much for this answer!